# Marketing Cloud Rest/Soap API Upsert into multiple Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions, integration, soap-api

I know that Rest & Soap API can be used to import data into Marketing Cloud from an external system, but does any of them offer the possibility to import into multiple Data Extensions from a single API Call? Or do you need a separate call for each Data Extension?

I was looking at the official documentation for the [Rest API Async Upsert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/updateDataExtensionIDAsync.html) and the [Soap API Upsert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/managing_data_in_data_extensions.html#upsert), but this information is not mentioned. Do you have any idea if this is possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upsert data into multiple data extensions with one API request. One request - one upsert DE